# An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement. Error

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update the sum of one table contents to another table using this query.

```
update c set  c.amountwithoutvat = SUM(c.amountwithvat / 1.25),
c.profitamount=(SUM(rp.amountwithtvat / 1.25) - (ps.netpurchaseprice*rp.qtysold)),
c.profitpercent= ((SUM(c.amountwithvat / 1.25) - (ps.netpurchaseprice*c.qtysold)) / SUM(c.amountwithvat / 1.25)) * 100
 from data.cashierdailysales c inner join receipts r on c.salesdate=r.RecDate
inner join data.receipt_productlines rp on r.seriesno=rp.seriesno 
inner join product_supplier ps on ps.productid=rp.productid 
inner join product_chain pc on pc.productid=ps.productid and pc.activesupplier=ps.supplierid
 where c.salesdate between CONVERT(date,'20-02-2014',104) and CONVERT(date,'03-03-2014',104)
```

But i get this error,

```
`an aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.
```

And when i use group by at the end I get,

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'`

Comment: Your syntax has nothing to do with MySQL.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: As i said. I'm trying to get the values from one table, calculate them sum them up and store them in another table.

Comment: Start with a `select` query that returns the results that you want for the update.  Your query is mixing aggregate functions with non-aggregate functions.  It has aggregates but no `group by` (which wouldn't be allowed anyway).  You have tagged the question "mysql", but you are using SQL Server functions.  It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

To update a table with the aggregate values of another table you have to [use a sub-query](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-157.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a view to calculate and load your table with it.

Comment: Please expand on your answer with some sample code.  One-line answers are liable to get deleted.